# Trigger jQuery after new content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought I solved it before since I dont get an error but turns out. On [this website here](http://chakraco.club/node/add/application), I have `add content buttons`. The system adds some text into these buttons but I need to remove them to match the design.

While I initially manage to remove the text, they appear again when `add content buttons` reload. I tried `onlick` and event delegation but neither worked so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {    
    //  Application add/edit form remove text from buttons
    $(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
    $(document).on("click",'.paragraphs-buttons button', (function() {
        $(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        })
    );
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your only problem is the unnecessary parenthesizes around your function click event. Can you try without it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    //  Application add/edit form remove text from buttons
    $(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
    $(document).on("click",'.paragraphs-buttons button', function() {
        $(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***Edited:
To remove the text contents, try using `text()` function on the span element within the button. I also repaired the code syntax, hope it'll work this time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {    
    //  Application add/edit form remove text from buttons
    $(".paragraphs-buttons button span").text("");
    $(document).on("click",'.paragraphs-buttons button', function () {
        $(".paragraphs-buttons button span").text("");
    });
});
```

***Old answer
I don't quite see what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to show it only onclick. remove the `$(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");` before the click event, cause you calling it twice, initially and when the click occurs. Hope that helps.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {    
    //  Application add/edit form remove text from buttons

    $(document).on("click",'.paragraphs-buttons button', (function() {
        $(".paragraphs-buttons button").html("<span class='icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span>");
        })
    );
});
```

To remove contents you can use `$(selector).html("");` or `$(selector).empty();`

Comment: Hi there! I want text inside button to be removed at initial load, thats why I have that line. When user clicks to one of those buttons, system loads another `add content button`, I want new button text to be removed too but thats where I'm failing.

Comment: So when the text should be there at all?

Comment: Never, but its coming from the system and website owner cant change it. Thats why I'm trying to remove it with jQuery

Comment: To remove contents you can use $(selector).html(""); or $(selector).empty().

Comment: Maybe I confused you here. I still want to append that icon. I just want to remove the text. It works at initial load but not for buttons loaded later

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you provide the link or html code of that part along with button, icon and text in it, please? Maybe there is a problem with selecting it. On the other side, you could also try `$(selector).text("");`

Comment: I checked it out, text() should definitely work, as I wrote in the edited answer, the only concern I have, it might take a bit time while buttons are loading after click, so if there will be no effect, you might want to use some delay too

Comment: Turns out, I didn't wrap it correctly, syntax error! Thank you very much for trying though!!